# Quickly Format/Convert Thousands' Space-Delimiter Numbers in Excel from Euro Data

Tags: excel

I imported a Scandinavian data set where the thousands are separated by spaces:

```
Col A               Col B
31 624              57 661
20 004              3 478
etc.
```

I need to convert these to US Excel's Number, but can't find a way. Only '`,`' is assumed for numbers. All calculations end up incorrect.

Comment: What if you did, say, `=TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""),"#,###.##")`

Comment: that worked Bruce. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to force the format with

```
=TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""),"#,###.##")
```